# how to make permalink in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to make permalink in codeigniter, yet i have a page in which i am getting `post_id` through get method, and showing all data which this post_id contains.

Now i want to get all data through `post_title` similarly as i am matching `post_id` now want to match `post_title`

```
$var = $_GET['post_id'];

    $all=$this->db->select('*');
    $get=$this->db->where("mypost.post_id =",$var); 
    $a=$this->db->get('mypost');
```

this is my sample code

Comment: Visit this link, maybe it will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653160/how-to-make-permalink-in-codeigniter-social-case


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653160/how-to-make-permalink-in-codeigniter-social-case

Comment: No my case is different kindly allow some one to give answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the like operator in your WHERE clause for string comparison if post titles are available like post IDs on the page:

```
$var = $_GET['post_title'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM myposts where mypost.post_title like $var";
$get = $this->db->query($query);
$a = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```